# How to set defalult selected items in selectOneRadio/selectCheckboxMenu by beans in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to create `selectOneRadio` list and `selectCheckboxMenu` which items get from related bean objects.
For non selected list it is working well.But how can i provide these lists with some item(s) selected by default.
My current `selectCheckboxMenu` code is like this.

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="trdays" 
             value="#{mybean.selectedDay}"
             label="Select Days">
      <f:selectItems value="#{mybean.dayList}" var="day"
       itemValue="#{day.value}" itemLabel="#{day.name}"/>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

it should look like this when page loaded and user haven't done anything yet.

[image: default page display]

**EDIT** 
Day Class :-

```
public class Day{

  private String name;
  private String value;

  //getters and setters

}
```

Comment: What is type of your `selectedDay` property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Value attribute of selectCheckboxMenu component should get the your default values. 
On bean side you should write a getter for **selectedDayList** and all **daylist**.

Example:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
            dayList= new ArrayList<String>();
            dayList.add("Mon");
            dayList.add("Tue");
            dayList.add("Wed");
            dayList.add("Thu");
            dayList.add("Fri");
            dayList.add("Sat");
            dayList.add("Sun");

            selectedDayList= new ArrayList<String>();
            selectedDayList.add("Tue");
            selectedDayList.add("Wed");
}


public List<String> getDayList()
    {
        return dayList;
    }

public List<String> getSelectedDaylist()
    {
        return selectedDayList;
    }
```

.xhtml page should be like this.

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="trdays" 
             value="#{mybean.selectedDaylist}"
             label="Select Days">
      <f:selectItems value="#{mybean.dayList}" var="day"
       itemValue="#{day.value}" itemLabel="#{day.name}"/>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: The explanation is good, but the code is at the wrong place. You should not put business logic in getter methods! Use the bean's (post)constructor.

Comment: I didn't want to make it longer but finally you're right. I'll fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just add default values in the `selectedDay` list (or array) in init method (with `@PostConstruct` annotation). These values should have same value as corresponding `itemValue` attribute (in your case this is `day.value`).

Comment: Same values according to the equals/hash comparing of things. For strings this works, for complex objects you have to implement the equals/hash methods yourself